# component.createimage returns null even headless() returning false

Tags: java, graphics, jpanel

I am trying to draw a graph.In which for double-buffering i am using CreateImage() method of component class. But with the same attributes as input this method randomly returns null value. When I searched i found out that this happens when GraphicsEnvironmemt.headless() returns true. then I print the value of GraphicsEnvironmemt.headless()  which always returning false. 
Is there any other cases when createimage() return null. I searched a lot but not able to get appropriate answer.

Answer (score 0):

As specified by the [Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#createImage(int,%20int))

> The return value may be null if the component is not displayable

Yes, this will happen if `headless` is false, but it will also happen if the `Component` is not attached to a displayed container.  A component becomes displayable when it is attached to  a native peer.  This will happen if the component has never been displayed on the screen or the window it is attached to (directly or indirectly) is disposed

You could use something like...

```
GraphicsConfiguration gc = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice().getDefaultConfiguration();
BufferedImage image = gc.createCompatibleImage(width, height, transparency);
```

which creates a `BufferedImage` which is optimised for use with the specified `GraphicsConfiguration`